# Where put database interaction in django templatetags

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm writing a simple templatetag that gets one item and call one of its methods to get and prepare some data. And I wonder where I should call it, in Node or in compiler? 
Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template tags shouldn't interact with your database at all, really.  At least not in the sense that you are interacting with your model/business data.  This would violate the separation of concerns that is one of the main reasons to use an MVC (er, MTV) style framework in the first place.

If you're talking about a data-driven template tag that interacts with the database for some reason to deal with only presentation-level stuff, then it should go in a method within your `Node` that is called within your `Node`'s `render` method.

```
class MyCustomNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def render(self, context):
        # do your db lookup here
        return some_string_using_the_db_stuff
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was looking for way to avoid directly getting data in view, cause it should not bother user with calling this model method. But if it should be called in view I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: Disagree with this. If you want, for example, a sidebar of most recent items to appear on several pages on your site, that's interacting with the database and yet the best place for it is in a templatetag.

Comment: @Daniel I would argue that there are ways of doing that where you still didn't need to have the DB interaction in the **templatetag code**, but also that's why I had a caveat in there - "recent items" isn't really doing lookups in the database to determine how to render something like I feared may have been the case for the OP

Comment: Roseman you could also use takes_context, and rely on the context to have the needed data, which would help main the separation of concerns. I would advise against template tag's querying the db, and instead explicitly utilize the view layer to give the data to the UI layer or template tag.